# Export Bendy bone squishy deformation?

Tags: rigging, export, bones, unity

I read that bendy bones cant be exported to other software, in my case Unity 3D. So people say you have to convert bendy bones to regular bones, then export it. Although i'm wondering if the "squishy" deformation you get with bendy bones able to be exported as well? In other words, the mesh deformation when you move bendy bones closer or further away, that is controlled with the volume settings in the stretch to modifier,

Answer (score 1):

Strech to modifier simply acts on scaling the bone, so yes, it's exportable: in pose mode select all deforming bones, go to pose menu > animation > bake action, turn on all preferences, and bake. Then you can delete all non deforming bones and export a simple rig without modifiers with ease.